# nginx shows default page instead of my site

Tags: nginx

i have three virtual machines and Apache on the first and second and nginx on the third here is my virtual hosts on the two Apache:

```
<virtualHost 192.168.80.140:8080>
ServerName united.com
ServerAlias www.united.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/united.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and:

```
<virtualHost 192.168.80.137:8080>
ServerName united.com
ServerAlias www.united.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/united.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and nginx conf:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
   upstream loadbalancedbackend {
           server 192.168.80.140;
           server 192.168.80.137;
     }
server {
     location / {
            proxy pass http://loadbalancedbackend;
          }
     }
}
```

also i set hosts file on my windows host machine:

```
192.168.80.150          www.united.com
```

which is the ip of my nginx. so my problem is when i try to www.united.com from the browser it show nginx default page ?

Answer (score 1):

In your apache configuration, you have specified to listen on port 8080 for the virtual hosts, but in your nginx configuration you don't specify port (thus defaulting to port 80 for http). Try to replace

```
server 192.168.80.140;
server 192.168.80.137;
```

with

```
server 192.168.80.140:8080;
server 192.168.80.137:8080;
```